# How to install a translation for a WP plugin?

Tags: plugins, translation

So I installed this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-email/

I need a Spanish translation. There is a link that takes you to a list of translation files: http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wp-email/i18n/

So I downloaded wp-email-es_ES.mo and wp-email-es_ES.po

How do I install a translation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Plugin uses [`load_plugin_textdomain()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_plugin_textdomain), which by default uses the Plugin's root directory as the path for the translation files.

So: simply add the translation files you downloaded to the Plugin root directory, and you *should* be good to go.

#### Edit

> > And you're using WordPress in es_ES?
>
> No, I just want to translate that plugin. It generates a form with fields such as "Your Name" "Your Email" "Your Remark" and I need that form translated in Spanish.

If you actually want WordPress to *use* those translation files, you have to *tell* it to use them, by changing `WPLANG` from `en_US` to `es_ES` in `wp-config.php`.

Comment: already added the two files to the plugin's root directory and I see no change.

Comment: And you're using WordPress in es_ES?

Comment: No, I just want to translate that plugin. It generates a form with fields such as "Your Name" "Your Email" "Your Remark" and I need that form translated in Spanish.

Comment: See updated answer. How do you expect WordPress to *know* to use those `es_ES` translation files, when you've configured it to use `en_US`?

Comment: Is there a way for WordPress to only use translation files for a particular plugin and leave everything else in English, untouched?

Comment: You could try *renaming* the translation files as `{domain}-en_US.mo` and `{domain}-en_US.po`, so that WordPress loads them using your default language settings.